# Confusion about HSRP Groups

Tags: cisco, multicast, hsrp

If I have a router that has several LANs on it, and each of these LAN is attached to a second router, do I need to use different HSRP groups for each LAN?

With this set up, each virtual gateway will be on a Layer 2 segment.  And within a router, no interface will have multiple gateways.

So, For example:

Router 1:

```
F0/0:
ip address 192.168.1.2 255.255.255.0
standby ip 192.168.1.1
F2/0:
ip address 192.168.2.2 255.255.255.0
standby ip 192.168.2.1
```

Router 2:

```
F0/0:
ip address 192.168.1.3 255.255.255.0
standby ip 192.168.1.1
F2/0:
ip address 192.168.2.3 255.255.255.0
standby ip 192.168.2.1
```

Will this work, or do I need `standby 1 ip 192.168.2.1` on the F2/0 interfaces? (When no group is specified, the default group is 0.)  Since according to the [RFC](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2281.html), the group number of the packet is in the HSRP multicast packets, my guess is that I don't need different groups, and that multiple groups are only needed when they are all on the same Layer 2 segment.  However, I haven't been able to find this setup....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If these LANs are all on separate L2 segments, you can safely use the same HSRP group number on all of them. I have seen this used in production with no issues; 100+ VLANs on a 6500 router pair all using HSRP group 1. Like you, I can't find any documentation blessing this right now.

One example I have seen where multiple HSRP groups used were used on the same interface was for combining subnets. For example, given the following two subnets:

```
interface Vlan1
 ip address 192.168.1.2 255.255.255.128
 standby 1 ip 192.168.1.1
!
interface Vlan2
 ip address 192.168.1.130 255.255.255.128
 standby 1 ip 192.168.1.129
!
```

If you wanted to combine them into one subnet (192.168.1.0/24), but maintain both existing HSRP addresses while hosts were reconfigured, the following configuration:

```
interface Vlan1
 ip address 192.168.1.2 255.255.255.0
 standby 1 ip 192.168.1.1
 standby 2 ip 192.168.1.129
!
```

Would allow you to do so.